# How do I push a new controller via UIButton, nested in a UIScrollView?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, uinavigationcontroller, uibutton

I have my views that are part of a tabBar. Each view has a navigationController.
In one of my views I have an embeded xib component. This is a scrolling view 
with UIButtons inside it.

I want to slide in another view, inside the navigationController when a person taps the button. I can get the taps, etc.

BUT, I can't figure out how to find the controlling navigationController of that page to push the new view into. Nothing seems to work that I have tried.

IS this possible?

Thanks

Comment: What does your view hierarchy look like? What objects have a reference to the navigation controller.

Comment: I a Home.xib. 


 IBOutlet FeaturedScroller *latestSubView;
 IBOutlet PopularScroller *popularSubView;

These scrollers are connected to another XIB which does the actual button rendering.

I have passed my subclassed UIButtons the navigationController, I put it in the app delegate.. but nothing makes it do it's thing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a reference to the navigation controller "down" your view hierarchy. Or pass another object that has a reference to the navigation controller "down". Or get the app delegate if it has a reference to the navigation controller.

Comment: I have seemingly done all those things.. and no matter what.. nothing happens.. though it is calling my other view controller and the button does go darker.

Comment: Do you know that the navigation controller is set up correctly--can you push a view right away after it's setup from the app delegate? Do you know that the reference had been properly passed down--did you use NSLog to display the pointer and make sure it is non-nil and matches what was created/setup?

Comment: Ok.. I am very confused.

I have a view HomeView where this "pushes" correctly:
- (void)openPopularArtists:(id)sender  {
 GalleryViewController *controller = [[GalleryViewController alloc]
           initWithNibName:@"GalleryViewController" bundle:nil];
 [[self navigationController] pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
 [controller release];
}

However, if I log out in the initWithNib :NSLog (@"1Nav is %@",[self navigationController]);  I GET NULL ??!!

I have a tabbar with controllers of navigationControllers each one with their own rootViewController.

help

Comment: Where is this NSLog statement? In GalleryViewController.m? Can you post the code with details as an update to your original question?